# Set Analysis in QlikView Current Vs Last Month

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to show Current Month Stats in a column and Last month stats in another column. While using Set Analysis I am facing issue that I can not get numbers for Last month

This is the statement I am using but it does not work:

```
/*Statement For Last Month*/
Sum( {$<CalMonthYear={"=$(=Max(CalMonthYear)-1)"}>} [DSP-Subscriber_Count])
/*Output here is the Sum of All Months */
```

Ideally it should give me the same output as following statement does

```
/***Last Month Hard Coded Script****/
Sum( {$<CalMonthYear={'Feb 2015'}>} [DSP-Subscriber_Count])
```

I have tried several variations but none seem to work. Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve the issue by first storing selected month number in a variable and using that variable in Set Analysis Expression.
Although I am still not sure why it wouldn't work without a variable. Anyway here is my solution for the problem

Declare Variable in Variable Overview Dialogue

```
vMaxSelectedDate_Num
```

Definition

```
= num(Month(Max(CalDate)))
```

Now Using CalMonth in Expression (CalMonth has Integer Value of Month)

```
Sum({$<[CalMonth]={$(vMaxSelectedDate_Num)}>}[Entity_To_Be_Added])
```

Similary I stored Last Month in a separate variable using below formula

```
= num(Month(AddMonths( Max(CalDate),-1)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't rely upon doing a -1 for a Month/Year combination, even if you're storing it as an integer (subtract 1 from 201501, for example...you don't get Dec 2014).

If you have day level dates in your model, do the arithmetic upon that. Perhaps something like:

```
{$<CalMonthYear={"=$(=Date(AddMonths(CurrentDate, -1), 'MMM YYYY'))"}>}
```

Comment: Also, bookmark and use this site whenever you're in the weeds. http://tools.qlikblog.at/SetAnalysisWizard/QlikView-SetAnalysis_Wizard_and_Generator.aspx?sa=

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer useful for my problem, but what I need really is to have:
Sum({$<[CalMonth]**< =**{$(vMaxSelectedDate_Num)}>}[Entity_To_Be_Added])